# Timeout in IO operation MySQL vb.NET 2012

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Just last friday this code was working perfectly and I was able to create a table in MySQL database but now its showing an error "Timeout in IO operation", need solution guys thanks.

```
Private Sub toCreateTable()

    Dim varString As String = "tablenaming"

    Dim Query As String
    Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=192.168.0.1; user=logging;  database=db_logging; port=3306; password=passing;")
    con.Open()

    Query = "CREATE TABLE  `" & varString & "` ( usernames varchar(50) ) "

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Query, con)

    If (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()) Then

    End If
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you connect to the server? Note when posting code... its best to change the server, username and password to xxxxxxx rather than show the real values.

Comment: yup using mysql workbench it is all good

Comment: and also when im using my web module made from php it is all good

Comment: Ok... could you pop a try catch on the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() and see if any exceptions are generated.

Comment: how should i do it mych?

Comment: an error shows and it is pointing on con.open() part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try catch.... Put this in place of your If Then End If.

```
Try
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    'any other code that needs to be completed after running query

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)

Finally
    con.Close()

End Try
```

Then let us know if you get any exception message

Comment: to add some details this is another description that it gives "timeoutexecption was unhandled"

Comment: OK... if pointing to con.Open check your connection string. Make sure server, db, user and password are all correct.

Comment: yupx i have checked it again and it is all right, and also weird cause it just worked last time arround thanks.

Comment: This is pointing to connectivity issues. Have you remoted onto the server running your app and check connectivity from that server to your db server?

Comment: your definitely write has to do with the Connect Timeout which concerns the connection thanks

Comment: your definitely right has to do with the Connect Timeout which concerns the connection thanks –